# Highcharts numbers too close

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i have a problem with highcharts when i have close values like 16 and 16.5, the numbers stay unreadable.
i 've searched in the Highcharts documentation and do not find any answers, there is any way to prevent this?

http://jsfiddle.net/01Lquzrm/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
        },
        subtitle: {
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 8.1, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 16.1, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [6.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The highcharts has no build-in antycollision algorithm for datalabels, but you can try to adapt [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/menXU/6/), which is based on `staggering labels`